# R package: NAMESPACE file is "not readable"

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, roxygen2

I have made some updates to my R package (named xrfr), and when I tried to run `devtools::check()` it told me that the NAMESPACE file is not readable. I have updated R and all my installed packages, and I have deleted the old NAMESPACE file to create a new one with `devtools::document()`, but I still get this error. I did move the package from my computer to my workplace's server, but that has not been a problem otherwise, so I do not believe that is the reason.

Here is the error:

```
> devtools::document()
i Updating xrfr documentation
i Loading xrfr
Writing NAMESPACE
Error: The specified file is not readable: myfolders\xrfr\NAMESPACE
```

Does anyone have an idea why? Thanks

Comment: This could be a couple of things:  antivirus programs sometimes make files unreadable while they're checking, so newly created files aren't readable for a second or two.  In this case your NAMESPACE file would be readable in an editor if you wait a few seconds.  Another possibility is that you don't have write permission on the directory you need to put it in.  Then you wouldn't see updates to it even if you wait to read it.

Comment: @user2554330 Thank you! I tried moving the package back to my computer and then it worked.

Comment: @user2554330 could you expand on "you don't have write permission on the directory you need to put it in"? I'm having the same issue where the folder is on a server but when I move the folder to my computer it then works. The strange thing is that I am able to write to the folder on the server normally e.g. `write_csv(iris, "iris.csv")`, is there something strange with how and `devtools::document()` would handle `NAMESPACE` that you are hinting at? thanks

Answer (score -1):

I also want to confirm the same problem in my environment. When I kept my development folder in a network drive, I had the same error for the `NAMESPACE` not being readable as [agryt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14779324/agryt) had. And then when I moved the entire folder to a local drive, the problem disappeared. I also had write permission on the network drive, but there is probably another reason related to the network drive use.

I am using devtools version 2.4.3.

Answer (score -1):

Install the latest roxygen2, `remotes::install_github("r-lib/roxygen2")`. Problem will be solved.

I guess you are using internet drive under the windows system.
See discussions at:

- https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/1443
- https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest/issues/181

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.

Comment: Solution may offend the author of `digest`. So, I did not provided directly. Revised.